# Chord Implementation in Android+Java

Tags: java, android, dht, chord

Here is the Problem.I am implementing Chord DHT in Android.I have started the server(not exactly server) at 5554 and that is where every new node gives request to join the circle.Now I compare the identifier hash of new node and hash of node at 5554 and updating the successor and predecessor of both the nodes.I am doing till this correctly.

Now my problem is if another node comes in,I have to update the predecessor and successor in 3 nodes accordingly.How do I update these? I use java. I am not asking the code.I am just asking the logic to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the stabilize() method, and call that regularly. Maybe periodically and/or after the ring's topology changed.
I myself also implemented way to get a node's idea of it's predecessor (it's used in the stabilize() method).
You should look at other [implementations](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/chord/faq.html#lang), though, if you haven't already.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on stabilize() method?